# Key value look up and reverse

Tags: mule, dataweave, mel

We have a Mule 3.9 application where we need to do a key value look up. We have a property file file with the values specified

```
key=value
key2=value2
```

We then have a PropertiesFactoryBean referencing this mapping file

```
 <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="MappingProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <spring:property name="singleton" value="true"/>
            <spring:property name="location" value="mappings.properties"/>
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
```

and in our code we set a session variable using

```
<set-variable variableName="ourValue" value="#[app.registry.MappingProperties[flowVars.key]]"/>
```

Which does the key look up.

This works fine but we also need to do the mapping in reverse. ie. we need to look up based on value and return the key, is it possible to do this? I know I could acheive this via Java component but could it be done via MEL / dataweave or some other Mule specific example?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of the bean is a [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), you should be able to use Java or Groovy to iterate over the keys and find a matching value.